# How does one find center of mass of 2d array of sensors with sensor value as 3rd dimension

Tags: opencv

I have an input device that gives me the pressures of a 2d array of sensors.

If I treat these pressures as the Z dimension, and the column and row of the sensor as the X and Y, what is the opencv way to find the center of mass, assuming a uniform density?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be the opencv way of calculating the mass center.  For a 2x2 array set to 5,5,5,10:

```
Mat m(2, 2, CV_8UC1);

m.at<unsigned char>(0,0) = 5;
m.at<unsigned char>(0,1) = 5;
m.at<unsigned char>(1,0) = 5;
m.at<unsigned char>(1,1) = 10;

Moments mm = moments(m,false);

Point3f mass_center(mm.m10/mm.m00,mm.m01/mm.m00,mm.m00/m.total()/2);
```

The mass center would be at .6,.6,3.125.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a thought experiment for a method, so don't be too harsh. So you have a set of points each with a location of X,Y and a weight Z.

Take any two points and find the center of mass for them. Replace these two points with a single point at the new X,Y and a new Z.

Keep doing this until you have only one point left, which is the answer you seek.

Comment: Yes, I think that would work.  But I bet there is a cute opencv method using moments that I'm searching for.